# Skip model validations defined in a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using the restful authentication plugin, but on my site I want to have a registration form without the "confirm password" field. Now the problem is that there are some validations hardcoded in the plugin module which is included in my User model.

```
# Authentication::ByPassword
validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_required?
validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => :password_required?
```

How can I disable these validations without patching the plugin? Will this do the trick if I redefine validations in my model? Or what would be the best practice in such case?

```
# user.rb
validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => Proc.new { false }
validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => Proc.new { false }
```

Comment: Ok, wrote some unit tests and redefining a validation doesn't help. Any alternatives?

Comment: For now, I just patched the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
save(false)
```

Or:

```
 update_attribute
```

to skip all or one validation.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that saving without validations or changing attributes directly is not an option.

Comment: Did you try to simply add a params[:password_confirmation] and copy the params[:password] in it? It could be done in a before filter if you extend the plugin

Comment: Apparently I needed to patch the plugin anyway for custom validation translations (I have 3 languages on my site). Thanks though, nice idea